# Get ID of closest Div not working twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a close button that I'm working on and am using 'onclick'.  When the user presses the button, I am trying to set the parent ID's display value to 'none'. Like below.

```
function displayNone() {
    var id= $('.btnClose').closest('div').attr('id');
    $('#'+id).css('display','none');
}


<div class="popup" id="dc-16-decision">
    <a href="#" onclick="displayNone();" class="btnClose">X</a>

</div>

<div class="popup" id="dc-16-implementation">
    <a href="#" onclick="displayNone();" class="btnClose">X</a>
</div>
```

I was able to get this to work once with the first link but anything after that does not work.  So, I put a test into JsFiddle and see that when I am clicking the second link, it is still returning the first link's parent ID instead of the second link's. I'm pretty new to this and am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried using $(this) instead of $('.btnClose') but it returns 'undefined'.

http://jsfiddle.net/5x7g96hu/

```
<script>
    function test() {
     var name = $('.btnClose').closest('div').attr('id');
    console.log(name);
}
</script>

<div class="popup" id="dc-16-decision">
    <a href="#" onclick="test();" class="btnClose">X</a>

</div>

<div class="popup" id="dc-16-implementation">
    <a href="#" onclick="test();" class="btnClose">X</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.btnClose').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest('.popup').hide(); });`

Comment: `$('.btnClose')` will fetch array of elements which matches the selection. So you get two objects always wrt your html. Since you have 2 elements `.closest` will always apply for first element in this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is due to the way you select the div to change display on:
Each time you click on a link, you call for the same selector with closest which will only consider the first element in the list of divs. I would suggest you simply bind a jQuery event to all your A tags like this:

```
$("A.btnClose").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Now when you will click a link, it's going to look for closest DIV of the clicked A tag.
You can even avoid using the id reference (like in my examole) itself because it is evident that you want to hide the div the A tag was in.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass click elements context to click handler using keyword `this` for targeting currently clicked element:

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
function test(obj) {
  var name = $(obj).closest('div').attr('id');
  console.log(name);
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="popup" id="dc-16-decision">
  <a href="#" onclick="test(this);" class="btnClose">X</a>
 </div>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jj8yLvdm/)**

You can bind the click event via jquery using:

```
$('a').click(function(){
 console.log($(this).closest('div').attr('id'));
});
```

**[Demo Using Jquery click handler](http://jsfiddle.net/j3rwspqb/)**

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Binding the jquery event did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid inline JS, but here is the way to find actual element on which event occur:

```
 function test() {
      var name = $(event.target).closest('div').attr('id');
    alert(name);
 }
```

Here "event" is implicit object which hold all the information of event on DOM element.

http://jsfiddle.net/5x7g96hu/3/